# Wrong "Like count" in Facebook Album Stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

we are using the facebook timeline phtot stream, to show the last photos on the website.
We are parsing the url: http://graph.facebook.com/132827113407662/photos

If you have a look at the 5th pic, it shows 25 likes.
If you look at this pic on fb (https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=635486689808366&set=a.132827113407662.19448.114902408533466&type=1), it shows 31 "Likes".

How can I get the correct number of "likes".
It seems, that the largest number in the stream (http://graph.facebook.com/132827113407662/photos) ist 25. Any like higher than 25 will be ignored in the stream.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Likes collection is paginated. You can read more about pagination [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/).
Looks like there is still no way to get all rows count for a collection using graph api request. 
But you can get it through [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/).

```
select like_info, object_id from photo where album_object_id = 132827113407662
```

Returns:

```
{
  "data": [  
     ...      
     {
       "like_info": {
         "can_like": true, 
         "like_count": 31, 
         "user_likes": false
       }, 
      "object_id": 635486689808366
     }, 
     ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Graph Api you can request fields summary like this: `?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(1)`

And the page/album/photo likes are contained in the `summary.total_count` object.

http://graph.facebook.com/132827113407662/photos?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(1)

This will give you as follows:

```
{
   "data": [
    {
        "id": "690240794332955",
        "created_time": "2013-10-31T18:11:07+0000",
        "likes": {
           "data": [
              {
                 "id": "100003293421476",
                 "name": "Rene Geels"
              }
           ],
           "paging": {
              "cursors": {
                 "after": "MTAwMDAzMjkzNDIxNDc2",
                 "before": "MTAwMDAzMjkzNDIxNDc2"
              },
              "next": "http://graph.facebook.com/690240794332955/likes?summary=1&limit=1&after=MTAwMDAzMjkzNDIxNDc2"
           },
           "summary": {
              "total_count": 78
           }
        }
    }
   ]
}
```